# how to break an enhanced for loop from a switch in java

Tags: java, foreach, switch-statement, break

I found this interesting thing you can break a enhance for loop with a break; statment but i want to know if it is possible to break a enhanced For loop from a switch statement inside that statement

For Example

```
String test = "(2.0+4.0)";

    for (char now : test.toCharArray()){

        switch (now) {

        case '(':
            // i want the loop to stop from this point
            break;
        case ')':
        case '/':
        case '*':
        case '+':
        case '-':
        }
    }
```

> Edited

Found the answer 
labeled break.
but im going Old school

```
String test = "(2.0+4.0)";
    boolean found = false;
    for (char now : test.toCharArray()){

        switch (now) {

        case '(':
            // i want the loop to stop from this point
            System.out.println(now);
            found = true;
            continue;
        case ')':
        case '/':
        case '*':
        case '+':
        case '-':
        }

        System.out.println("im out of switch");
        if(found)break;
    }
    System.out.println("out of Loop");

}
```

That Did it

Thanks For All the Answers

Comment: It's called a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Comment: That `continue` should be `break` in your old-school example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a label in the for loop and break it within the switch statement.

```
public static void main (String args[]){
        String test = "))(2.0+4.0)";
        int i = 0;
        labelLoop :
            for (char now : test.toCharArray()){
                switch (now) {
                case '(':
                    break labelLoop;
                case ')':
                case '/':
                case '*':
                case '+':
                case '-':
                i++;
                }
            }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

This will print 2.

Comment: Worked like a charm but since using label is not a good practice im gonna go with old school

Comment: @Fuzaill'Corder: No, it's good practice since you haven't `goto/label` as same as GW-Basic, it's a polite way to break nested loops and everyone by seeing that label can find out the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Use statement labeling:

```
    a: for (char now : test.toCharArray()){

        switch (now) {

        case '(':
            break a;
        case ')':
        case '/':
        case '*':
        case '+':
        case '-':
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the following syntax:

```
label:
for (char now : array) {
    switch(now) {
    case '(':
        break label;
    }
}
```

This works for all kinds of loops in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can `break` the block:

```
the_block:
for (char now : test.toCharArray()){
   switch (now) {
   case '(':
       break the_block;

   // ...
   }
}
```

### What it means? Is it a goto/label mechanism? ... No!

Maybe someone get confused by this syntax, many expect after `break the_block;` everything after the label must be executed again. No. In fact, `the_block` is a name for the following block. `break the_block;` is not a `goto the_block;`. It means, break the block which is named `the_block`. So, by breaking the block, you will expect the control goes out of the block and it correct.

To make it a bit more clear I've put a `{}` around the loop:

```
the_block: {
    for (char x : array){
       switch (x) {
       case '(':
           break the_block;

       // ...
     }
}
```

And, since it's not a `goto/labal` mechanism, it's not a bad practice, everything is clear and readable.